# What does this operator do?

Tags: c, linux, unix, arduino, driver

I am writing a Linux driver for my chinese arduino. At one moment I need to change the baud rate. I looked for examples and found that listing:

```
Listing 2 - Setting the baud rate.

struct termios options;

/*
 * Get the current options for the port...
 */

tcgetattr(fd, &options);

/*
 * Set the baud rates to 19200...
 */

cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);

/*
 * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
 */

options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

/*
 * Set the new options for the port...
 */

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

The next to last line of code has the `|=` operator. What does it do? I've never seen it before.

Comment: `a |= b;` -> `a = a | b;` (with the difference being that `a` is evaluated only once with the `|=` operator, thanks Filipe!)

Comment: `|=` is compound bit-wise `inclusive OR` assignment operator.

Comment: @Kninnug This is generally true, but to be technically correct you should mention that `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b` with the exception that `a` is only evaluated once. This is important if the expression `a` has side effects.

Comment: Related: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/119527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
```

is generally equivalent to

```
options.c_cflag = options.c_cflag | (CLOCAL | CREAD);
```

except `options.c_cflag` is evaluated only once, which doesn't matter in the above expression, but it would matter if `options.c_cflag` had any side effects (for example, if it were `*options.c_cflag++`)

Comment: If you want to make an answer out of this, at least make it complete. Did you read my comment?

Comment: If it *were* `options.cflag++`, it'd be undefined behavior. Try `*options.cflagptr++`.

Comment: @EOF Actually, it wouldn't be undefined behavior, it just won't compile, as `options.c_cflag++` isn't an lvalue. I fixed the answer using your example.